# Adding a simple "pause" function inside this html5 audio code?

Tags: html, audio

I've tried the simple controls="pause" code but I don't want a visible music player to show up. I want the pause function to happen when I click my "play button" a second time.

Is there a way to insert a "pause on click" function into this code? I don't want to see a separate button.

Thanks!

```
$</div></td>
    $<td class="<div class="crowplayer">
   $ <a onclick="this.firstChild.play()" class="crowplayer"><audio $src="BirdSongsOGGshort/CrowCOedit.ogg"></audio>&#9658;</a>
$</div></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The `controls` attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> <...>
>
> If the attribute is present, or if scripting is disabled for the media element, then the user agent should expose a user interface to the user. This user interface should include features to begin playback, pause playback <...>
>
> [source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#attr-media-controls)

Thus, `controls="pause"` is invalid.
If for some reasons you don't want to specify the `controls` attribute, then you can add your own play/pause `button`:

```
var audio = document.querySelector('audio'),
    button = document.querySelector('button')
;
button.addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    if (audio.paused) {
      button.textContent = 'Pause';
      audio.play();
    } else {
      button.textContent = 'Play';
      audio.pause();
    }
  },
  false
);
```